# What are some real time use cases of implementing slots in salesforce lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

**SLOTS in Salesforce LWC**

What are some real time use cases of implementing slots in salesforce lightning web components

Answer (score 1):

The "real use case" you are asking for depends on who and why someone would use this. In this [lightning-card example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/example), the footer might be present or not, it might contain a different text, or buttons. Same thing with the actions: they might be there or not.

Imagine a scenario where your component evaluates the permissions a current user has, or evaluates some criteria with a record on the database, and uses this as the condition to show a specific thing on the footer, or enable/disable a specific action.

At the end, slots help with [composition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_compose_intro) of components.